# how to detect that you rails app is running from a rails runner

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this line on my code

```
puts "done clearing for #{@transfer_account.inspect}"
```

I want it to run only if i'm running the cron job (with rails runner)

so trying to implement

```
puts_if_runner "done clearing for #{@transfer_account.inspect}"
```

The command is 
`bundle exec rails runner -e production "Transfer.process!"`

Comment: with or without rails runner?

Comment: if ran by runner - output, if not run by runner - don't output

Comment: how are you invoking the crontab command?

Comment: hi @emaillenin , I added the answer to the question

Answer (score 2):

Since every Rails application is a Railtie, you can use the Railties API to set a flag at process start time.  I have this in my `config/application.rb`:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  # Are we in rails runner?
  config.is_rails_runner = false
  runner do |app|
      app.config.is_rails_runner = true
  end

  #...
```

Then later on you can test this flag:

```
if Rails.application.config.is_rails_runner
  puts "done clearing for #{@transfer_account.inspect}"
end
```